# Regularizing a file path in C#

Tags: c#, file, path

Is there a convenient function to regularize a file path in c#?

I have a command-line program which accepts a file path from the user. If they are being too clever, they might supply something like "c:\\mypath", which c# represents internally as "c:\\\\mypath"

I'd like to process the paths so they are regularized to "c:\\mypath"

I could use a string replace where I replace "\\\\" with "\\", but is there a more elegant platform independent way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=VS.110%29.aspx). it will handle it for you and will provide you all the functionality you want.

Comment: Indeed. The method is question is Path.GetFullPath()... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @"C:\myPath\"